# UI5 JavaScript code is not working, semantic

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My code is not working. I got the error: `parsing error:unexpected token {` It's on the third to last parenthesis.

```
sap.ui.controller("sigpad.sigpad.controller.View1", {
    onInit: function() {
        this.getView().byId("html").setContent("<canvas id='signature-pad' width='400' height='200' class='signature-pad'></canvas>");
    },

    onSign: function(oEvent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = 276;
        canvas.height = 180;
        context.fillStyle = "#fff";
        context.strokeStyle = "#444";
        context.lineWidth = 1.5;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var disableSave = true;
        var pixels = [];
        var cpixels = [];
        var xyLast = {
        };
        var xyAddLast = {
        };
        var calculate = false; {
            //functions
            function remove_event_listeners() {
                canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
                canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
                canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
                document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
            }
            function get_coords(e) {
                var x, y;
                if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
                    var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
                    var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;
                    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
                    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
                }
                else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
                    x = e.layerX;
                    y = e.layerY;
                }
                else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
                    x = e.offsetX;
                    y = e.offsetY;
                }
                return {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };
            };
            function on_mousedown(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
                document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
                document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
                empty = false;
                var xy = get_coords(e);
                context.beginPath();
                pixels.push('moveStart');
                context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
                pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
                xyLast = xy;
            };
            function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                var xy = get_coords(e);
                var xyAdd = {
                    x: (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
                    y: (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
                };
                if (calculate) {
                    var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
                    var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
                    pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
                }
                else {
                    calculate = true;
                }
                context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                context.stroke();
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
                xyAddLast = xyAdd;
                xyLast = xy;
            };
            function on_mouseup(e) {
                remove_event_listeners();
                disableSave = false;
                context.stroke();
                pixels.push('e');
                calculate = false;
            };
        }
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
    },

    /***********Download the Signature Pad********************/
    saveButton: function(oEvent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        link.download = 'sign.jpeg';
        link.click();
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        })
    },

    /************Clear Signature Pad**************************/
    clearButton: function(oEvent) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            penWidth: '1'
        }),
    }

});
```

Comment: There's a lot to be said in caution of copy&paste, but it would be of advantage for program output&messages, compared to, e.g., `"parsing error:unexpeted token {"`. `on the third last parenthese` That `}` comes a surprise to me, too. Do you want more declarations or a `;`?

Comment: What is all of this to do with `semantic`?

Answer (score 0):

Its the comma. I usually use http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html to validate my JS code in such cases.

```
sap.ui.controller("sigpad.sigpad.controller.View1", {

onInit: function() {
    this.getView().byId("html").setContent("<canvas id='signature-pad' width='400' height='200' class='signature-pad'></canvas>");
},


onSign : function(oEvent){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 276;
    canvas.height = 180;
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.strokeStyle = "#444";
    context.lineWidth = 1.5;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var disableSave = true;
    var pixels = [];
    var cpixels = [];
    var xyLast = {};
    var xyAddLast = {};
    var calculate = false;
    {   //functions
        function remove_event_listeners() {
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        }

        function get_coords(e) {
            var x, y;

            if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
                var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
                var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;

                x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
                y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
            } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
                x = e.layerX;
                y = e.layerY;
            } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
            }

            return {
                x : x, y : y
            };
        };

        function on_mousedown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            empty = false;
            var xy = get_coords(e);
            context.beginPath();
            pixels.push('moveStart');
            context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
            pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
            xyLast = xy;
        };

        function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var xy = get_coords(e);
            var xyAdd = {
                x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
                y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
            };

            if (calculate) {
                var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
                var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
                pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
            } else {
                calculate = true;
            }

            context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            xyAddLast = xyAdd;
            xyLast = xy;

        };

        function on_mouseup(e) {
            remove_event_listeners();
            disableSave = false;
            context.stroke();
            pixels.push('e');
            calculate = false;
        };
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);

},


/***********Download the Signature Pad********************/

saveButton : function(oEvent){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); 
    link.download = 'sign.jpeg';
    link.click(); 
    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
    })
},

/************Clear Signature Pad**************************/

clearButton : function(oEvent){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
          penWidth : '1'
    })
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used such validators and they said that the code is correct. I paste it in my editor but now i get tons of new errors. Now i get errors on every function start: "Move function declaration to function body root"

Comment: I took a deeper research: i guess it has something todo with a specific  "use strict"; command... any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is, that i cannot define a function in another function. Why is this not possible? it should be?!

Comment: So, somehow i have to activate a rules to allaw inner declarations... any suggestions?